# Android - Why the click event isn't trigged

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-animation, autocompletetextview

I'm facing a problem with the focus on my application. I'm trying to catch the click event to animate my edittext, but for a reason I don't understand, sometimes my edittext is focused but the `click event` is not trigged.

The user has to click a 2nd time to start the animation.

I've got 2 `AutocompleteTextView` in my `SherlockFragment`.

Is it possible that come from the `animation` I'm doing ?

Edit:

```
    mEtWhere.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "mEtWhere've been clicked");
                    if (!mllWhereHasBeenClicked) {
                        mllWhereHasBeenClicked = true;
                        if (mAlphaFrameLayout != null) {
                            animate(mAlphaFrameLayout).setDuration(ANIM_DURATION / 2).alpha(0.9f);
                        }
                        if (mllWhere != null) {
                            oldllWhereYpos = ViewHelper.getY(mllWhere);
                            Log.v(TAG, "OldYWhereLLpos: " + oldllWhereYpos);
                            animate(mllWhere).setDuration(ANIM_DURATION).y(25.0f);
                            mBringToFrontView(mllWhere);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is the code to reset the position of all my edittexts

```
private void resetPositionViews() {
    closeKeyBoard();

    if (mAlphaFrameLayout != null && ViewHelper.getAlpha(mAlphaFrameLayout) > 0.0f) {
        animate(mAlphaFrameLayout).setDuration((7 / 4) * ANIM_DURATION).alpha(0.0f);
        mBringToFrontView(mAlphaFrameLayout);
    }

    if (ViewHelper.getY(mllWho) == 25.0f && mEtWho.isFocused() && mllWhoHasBeenClicked) {
        Log.i(TAG, "mEtWho has the focus");
        Log.i(TAG, "Back to oldllWhoYpos: " + oldllWhoYpos);
        animate(mllWho).setDuration(ANIM_DURATION).y(oldllWhoYpos);
        mllWhoHasBeenClicked = false;
    }

    if (ViewHelper.getY(mllWhere) == 25.0f && mEtWhere.isFocused() && mllWhereHasBeenClicked) {
        Log.i(TAG, "mEtWho has the focus");
        Log.i(TAG, "Back to oldllWhoYpos: " + oldllWhereYpos);
        animate(mllWhere).setDuration(ANIM_DURATION).y(oldllWhereYpos);
        mllWhereHasBeenClicked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: There would be too much to post, I've just post the listener on the click event and the function I'm using to reset the `edittext` positions.